# Add mobile number to Facebook contact?

Tags: contacts, facebook, go-contacts

My Android phone connected to Facebook and grabbed all my friends. Now I want to edit their info and add a mobile number, but it does not let me do that; it only lets you change their ringtone and a few other little options.

I am also using GO Contacts from Go Launcher. It's a little annoying when I click "edit a Facebook contact" and it goes to the phone's default contact sheet.

If I click a person I input manually it will go to that person in the Go Contact app and give me extra options and all that good stuff.

Is this a problem with Go Contacts or something? Can anyone recommend something better? Needs to have a dark skin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your contact list, select the Facebook contact that you would like to edit.  Click the menu button and choose Edit Contact.  You'll see an indication that the user is a Facebook contact and may not be edited.  Now click the Menu button again and choose New contact.  This will create a new contact in your address book and merge the Facebook profile information with that contact.  You may now edit the contact to have additional details, such as a phone number.